# How to install mtools by pip on Mac OS?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I followed this instruction to install `mtools`: https://github.com/rueckstiess/mtools/blob/develop/INSTALL.md. I tried both by `pip` and building from source but failed to launch it. I got below error when trying to launch `mlaunch`. I see this error relates to python and I am not familiar with python. Does anyone have any idea on this error?

```
$ mlaunch
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/mlaunch", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('mtools==1.2.4.dev0', 'console_scripts', 'mlaunch')()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 565, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2697, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2370, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2376, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mtools-1.2.4.dev0-py2.7.egg/mtools/mlaunch/mlaunch.py", line 40, in <module>
    raise ImportError("Can't import pymongo. See http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/ for instructions on how to install pymongo.")
ImportError: Can't import pymongo. See http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/ for instructions on how to install pymongo.
```

Comment: Have you installed `pymongo`? The error states that it is missing `pymongo`. Try `pip install pymongo` and run `mlaunch` again.

Comment: it works fine by installing `pymongo`. Thanks.

Comment: Wonderful. I will write an answer so that you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message in the trace states:

> ImportError: Can't import pymongo. See http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/ for instructions on how to install pymongo.

This means that you are missing a dependency called `pymongo` to run `mlaunch`.

You can install `pymongo` by running the following command:

```
python -m pip install pymongo
```

For more information on how to install `pymongo`see the official documentation: https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/installation.html